# Cross compilation of libraries that dynamically or statically linked with system libraries

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, g++, cross-compiling, ld

I am trying to cross compile some dependency libs for **RaspberryPi** target system, and host system is Linux with **GCC** compiler. For example, let's say that one of those libs has dependency on linkage stage and being linked with one of the system's static or dynamic libraries. 
How this case is resolved by linker? (Because those **.a** or **.so** files can be different on target system, so probably program on **RaspberryPi** will crash in this case). How to make it work in a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build environment that the cross-compiler provides is more accurately described as a *cross-toolchain*.  It needs to provide everything you need:  Not just the compiler, but also the assembler, linker, and all run-time support libraries.  That includes a C library (maybe glibc, maybe something else), the GCC run-time library (libgcc and libgcc_s), and the C++ run-time library (libstdc++).  But the build environment also needs copies of all the libraries your software needs to build, typically both header files and static libraries or dynamic shared objects for the target.  In particular, you cannot use the installed header files on the host because they might have the wrong definitions and declarations for the target.

Some programmers simply copy their dependencies (which are not system libraries) into their source tree, so that the cross-build environment can stay minimal.  But then these libraries have to be tracked and updated as part of the project, which can be cumbersome.

Comment: My dependencies for project are OpenCV 3.4.3 that built from source (so it may have some internal linking with something from system) and raspicam. So in this case I need to find all libraries that OpenCV depend on build time and build them from source for arm as well? o_O

Comment: Yes. You could perhaps use a pre-existing cross toolchain with all the required packages, but I don't know of any remaining effort with a large package set since [Emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/) stopped. Or you could simply build natively, possibly with emulation, and use a standard GNU/Linux distribution.